# Adding Toleration to Chart From Helm Values File

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3, cert-manager

I have few nodes and all of them have taints. I want to add toleration to the required pods / deployments of helm charts. The issue is I can specify that in the values file,

```yaml
---
installCRDs: true

tolerations:
  - key: foo
    operator: "Equal"
    value: bar
```

but this only works for one deployment/pod which is created by the cert-manager.

```
cert-manager           deployment.apps/cert-manager                1/1     1            1           3m40s
cert-manager           deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector     0/1     1            0           3m40s
cert-manager           deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook        0/1     1            0           3m40s
```

```
cert-manager           pod/cert-manager-cainjector-6cd8d7f84b-z4pkc     0/1     Pending   0          3m35s
cert-manager           pod/cert-manager-startupapicheck-zlkn9           0/1     Pending   0          3m24s
cert-manager           pod/cert-manager-webhook-64d76ab6c-9g698         0/1     Pending   0          3m35s
```

```
cert-manager   job.batch/cert-manager-startupapicheck   0/1           3m33s      3m33s
```

All deployments and pods other than the main one are basically saying could not tolerated taint thats why they could not scheduled when I describe them.

When I try the same thing for the other charts, they are working fine. But helper pods/deployments of cert-manager are not obtaining toleration specified in the values file. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need three tolerations, as the main toleration only applies for the `cert-manager`.

So we need one for chain injector and webhook.

```
webhook:
 tolerations:
  - key: foo
    operator: "Equal"
    value: bar
```

and injector

```
cainjector:
 tolerations:
  - key: foo
    operator: "Equal"
    value: bar
```

You can explore the default here [cert-manager-value-path](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cert-manager/cert-manager/1.9.0?modal=values&path=webhook.tolerations)